# Is it possible to specify a wildcard in Diazo <notheme if-path=… rule?

Tags: plone, diazo

If not, can I do this with inline XSLT? And if so, how?

I assume it's not possible, based on a [search for "wildcard" in the Diazo docs](http://diazo.org/search.html?q=wildcard) but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

This would be particularly handy in allowing the ZMI to pass through unthemed.

E.g.

```
<notheme if-path="manage*" />
<notheme if-path="portal*" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We tried regex matching with collective.xdv, but it didn't work too well - just think about what happens when someone creates the page named "management". Even `manage_*` ends up including the manage_translations page, which should be themed. Our current best practice is to use:

```
<rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">
```

I hope we'll be able to find a way to patch in the X-Theme-Disabled response.setHeader to the relevant bits of DTML (and a few ZPTs) in the ZMI.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an XPath expression :

```
<notheme if="contains($path, 'manage')"/>
```

But be careful though ;-)

Comment: is it possible to match on the beginning of a path? Like "^/manage" ?